# Which Windows 7 log file contains audio jack connections/disconnections information?

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, headphone-jack

I have a problem with my new computer. Sometimes a toast is displayed telling that headphones has been connected to front panel of my PC case, and i never connected a headphone to that audio jack connector. This front panel is connected to the motherboard so it is directly related with the integrated sound card of the motherboard. I tried formatting, with two operating systems (win 7 & 10) and same problem.

There are two possibilities. The motherboard can have a problem or the PC case can have a problem. I connected the front panel of the PC case to another computer with windows 7 and i will leave this all the night on. I need a log file or something to check the next morning if an event of connecting/disconnecting a headphone to the front panel has bent detected or not.

Is there a log file in Windows 7 for that?

Answer (score 0):

One place to look at is the Event Viewer, which you can access with [these instructions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7). My audio device's logs are located under the Custom Views folder. You might be able to find more information about your problem there.

It's possible that your device won't log headphone connection events (like mine), in which case I'd recommend running screen capture software if you can. Good luck!